# What CPU goes well for rendering / gaming on a RX 470 aside from the i3 6100?

Tags: processor, gaming, rendering

I bought this RX 470 recently for a good price, and now for Black Friday I am buying something that I intend not to bottleneck my GPU for gaming.

After browsing for a long time, I see many people recommending the i3 6100 going besides the RX 470. However, I often stream and use CPU rendering on my personal 3D projects. Therefore, I believe something with two cores would't be the perfect thing for streaming and rendering.

Any other budget recommendations that would do a good performance on both rendering and gaming?

Comment: I run an i3 6100 alongside an R9 380, which serves me perfectly well for gaming and video editing - you should be fine with that.

Comment: you mention "budget recommendations."  What is your price range?

Comment: @NZKshatriya I suppose something under ~220$ would be perfect. But still, I could be open expand my budget until the time I buy

Comment: @ArtOfCode hmmm, I am not sure if this applies to the i3 6100, but I've seen multiple websites comparing cores, and the difference between rendering times is insane, which might be worth a few extra bucks. Edit: though, looking at [this website](http://blenchmark.com/cpu-benchmarks), it has really, really impressive results for its price.

Comment: Also, after looking at the prices, it seems like no such CPU would perform this good at this price tag. No matter how many websites I look, I find it such a high risk buying this and realizing it is not as good as it seemed.

Comment: Any [cheap i5](http://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?name=I5-6400BOX) would work. If you're willing to wait 2 or 3 months, the Kaby Lake and Zen releases would give you more options. What software do you use? If it supports GPU acceleration, you may be better off spending he extra $50 on the GPU. Really, more information would be great.

Comment: @frankerzederede: Well, I'd say mine has been as good as was promised. Which isn't to say that it'll definitely, 100% certain, be what you want - but it's a review from someone who's using it, which is better than unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: Welp, I think that in the bottom line all I am really left to is what I expected: the I3 6100 and the I5 6400. The price gap is huge, and the I3 is screaming at me quite a lot. Thanks for the input people.

Comment: If ~$220 is your limit, you're looking at an i5-6600k